# Better way to get rid of leading zeroes in a date - Excel formula?

Tags: excel, formula

I came up with this solution to display today's date without leading zeroes in the month or the day when it's a single digit (so instead of 08/03/2017 it would be 8/3/2017, etc.):

`=TEXT(MONTH(NOW()),"0") & "/" & TEXT(DAY(NOW()),"0") & "/" & TEXT(YEAR(NOW()), "0000")`

Displays:

[image: Date displayed]

That formula displays today's date. Typically I'd say whatever and move on, but some of my cells are displaying a range of dates (the first of the month, the current day, and the last day of the month etc.), so what I now have in some of my cells is a very long chain of formulas.

**Is there a simpler way to display the dates without leading zeroes (and as text)?**

Comment: Change the format. right click format cells date with type *3/14/2001 local english us.  or create a custom format.  format 03/14/01 will display leading zeros where as *3/14/2001 will not.  Why does it need to be text?  Shouldn't dates always be stored as dates? that way the sheet knows the difference between 1/4/2017 (January 4th) and (April 1st.)  otherwise how do we know i'ts not dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy?  if you have to store multiple, I think you either need to pivot the data or use multiple columns...

Comment: You mean like using the built-in ability to format cells as dates without resorting to some silly kludge with a long string of function calls in a formula?

Comment: It needs to be text because the string includes characters like "-", so in order for me to include those I've had to convert the dates to text.

Comment: @KenWhite As I just answered xQbert, the date has to be **text**, because of what else is in the cell with it. It's not a single date in a cell - sometimes it's a long string that also contains my date.

Comment: if range of dates for '9/1/2017 - 12/1/2017' example, you need to use two columns Date start date end.  and treat them as dates.  Doing anything else imo is just going to cause heartache and headache later.  Don't overload cells w/ different types of data

Comment: @xQbert If I were creating this template myself, that's what I'd do - but right now I'm making an old company template dynamic, so I have to work with what already exists.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the image but from the sounds of it wouldn't this do the trick:  `=TEXT(NOW(),"m/d/yyyy")`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  looks good to me :P

Comment: I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help files:
`Text` makes use of *Format Codes* to display numbers in a more readable format, or to combine numbers with text or symbols.

So, the text function is saying `=TEXT(Value you want to format, "format you want to apply")`

The general format for a date would be something like `d/m/yyyy` to display month & day with no leading 0 and four digit year.  You could write `=TEXT(TODAY(),"A")` and it would convert todays date to the letter A.

In your case you need `=TEXT(TODAY(),"m/d/yyyy")`

Comment: For some reason I remember thinking this wouldn't work... but apparently I was wrong... If something comes up again that messes it up I'll let you know, but I think this works! Thanks-